# Is it possible to use linq in SQL Management Studio or use it in inline sql?

Tags: c#, linq, ssms

I would like to offload the work of generating an sql statement from the application to the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot, but if you want to translate LINQ queries you can use this tool: http://www.linqpad.net/  It can generate the SQL so if you invested a lot in LINQ, you can use this to create stored procs or queries for SQL.

Answer (score -2):

LINQ is part of C# (and other .net languages). It has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: +1, although it does have a *little* to do with SQL, since LINQ to SQL can translate to T-SQL ;p

Comment: @Mark Seemann: LINQ to SQL surely does (although that still won't help the OP). LINQ itself however, does not.

Comment: Darkon_ linq to sql is a subset of LINQ, so it does. In addition, the VB.NET Team created LINQ because they were looking for a durable way to access databases which will not get deprecated (again) after every new version of Visual Studio. Basically, an enterprise user told them that he's just been writing the same old database code for the last 20 years, yet in a different format every 2 years or so. Thats when they decided they must do LINQ to write once and have forever, and to their credit, the same linq code still continues to be useful after all these years, even from first version.

Comment: @DaRKoN_ of course, if you're using c# you will barely have any of the LINQ keywords/operators/expressions and will need to use explicit extension methods to get things done, but if you're using VB.NET, you will have the array of preserved keywords to write LINQ queries just like you would in SQL - so your queries will last forever, unless (or until) one day when they get rid of LINQ for something else. Point being, dude no longer needs to re-write his data access code every 2 years to do the same thing but with different "format" or method. Now, one line lasts forever. hurray to the VB team:)

Comment: @MarkSeemann LINQ was created by the VB.NET Team in order to be able to do LINQ to SQL (to use linq to access databases), feel free to read my msgs above.